# iCloud coredata detecting activity...?

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud, uimanageddocument

Let's say I decide to rebuild the store from the cloud and provide this as a store option:
`NSPersistentStoreRebuildFromUbiquitousContentOption`

Besides attaching observers to the following:
`NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification` (for detecting receipts and other files being downloaded)
`NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification` (for detecting when the store is being swapped out)

Is there any other events I can listen for and provide a little better feedback to the user?   I'd love to provide a progress bar or something, store 20% download, 40% download, etc.      Right now it can take minutes to actually get to the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification` with no way to watch the background progress.

With no progress bar or anything, I'm thinking users will think things have crashed...   Obviously I can add a message hold tight... But, not ideal.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: You can monitor the number of files and the download percentage from the metadata query and translate that into some sort of progress bar.  Check the sample apps here which does show percent downloaded but only in the Backup File Manager when selecting to download a backup from iCloud.  But you could use the same method for monitoring the downloaded Core Data files.
http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/

Comment: That doesn't sound like it would be very reliable when using Core Data. Can you point to a specific example on that page that would show how this is supposed to work?

Comment: I've experimented a little with Duncan's idea by storing all the NSMetadataItem's in an array as it discovers updates and such and checking percentDownloaded, but in most cases they "current".   So something else must be happening in the background that metadata query isn't reporting when it tries to rebuild the store...   Also I very rarely get a percent that is not nil, probably because the core data logs are so small, it is either not downloaded or current.   That happens pretty fast and the rest of the time is spent waiting...

Comment: Well this may not be effective in the case of a rebuild because it's possible all the files are already downloaded so it would not be an indicator.  I use it in the sample app to detect when there is network activity - so execute a transaction and save and log files get uploaded to iCloud.  So if you are using iCloud then you can be pretty sure that something will be uploaded if you perform a save (and there were changes).  By monitoring the upload status of files you can tell when your device has synced up to iCloud - it seems pretty reliable. Similarly for downloads...

Comment: BTW in the sample app I activate the network activity indicator when files need syncing.  In some situations you have to activate a particular peer device to fix up the syncing - I assume this may occur in situations where  a file was partially uploaded from a device and the device went off-line or where the network is unavailable for your device to upload to iCloud.